# Calculating covariance and ICC in mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, covariance

I'm a bit confused on how to start calculating by hand the covariance and intraclass correlations for mixed effects models. For example, in the particular example below:

$$
y_{ijk} = \beta'\boldsymbol{x}_{ijk} + \theta_i + \omega_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}
$$

where $\theta_i \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, \tau^2)$, $\omega_{ij} \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, \phi^2)$, and $\epsilon_{ijk} \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $\theta_i$ and $\omega_{ij}$ represent random intercepts for two different levels, with random effects being independent.

Is there anyone that can give me some steps to get started, or a link to similar solved/explained examples?

Answer (score 3):

Because you have two nested levels, you have two intra-correlation coefficients depending on which level you're looking at. The elements of the marginal covariance matrix will look as follows:

$$\mbox{var}(Y_{ijk}) = \tau^2 + \phi^2 + \sigma^2,$$
$$\mbox{cov}(Y_{ijk}, Y_{ijk'}) = \tau^2 + \phi^2, \quad \mbox{for } k' \neq k,$$
$$\mbox{cov}(Y_{ijk}, Y_{ij'k}) = \tau^2, \quad \mbox{for } j' \neq j.$$

Hence, you will have two intraclass correlations,

$$\rho_1 = \frac{\tau^2 + \phi^2}{\tau^2 + \phi^2 + \sigma^2},$$

and

$$\rho_2 = \frac{\tau^2}{\tau^2 + \phi^2 + \sigma^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

According to your model specification, we have

$Cov(Y_{ijk}, Y_{ijk'}) = \phi^2$

$Corr(Y_{ijk}, Y_{ijk'}) =\frac {\phi^2}{\sigma^2}$     for $k \ne k'$.

So after you get the estimates of ${\phi^2}$ and ${\sigma^2}$, just plug them in to get the estimate of the covariance and correlation coefficient.

But it is very hard to get the estimate of ${\phi^2}$ and ${\sigma^2}$ by hand.